# Copy and add another month to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have 'mytable' in SQL with ID, date and other columns.

Date field is in format 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

I want to write a PHP script to copy the rows of a given month and paste them in the next month with exactly the same values. Say, I want to copy the data from Dec-2013 to Jan-2014, how can I write the sql query do that?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table 
AS 
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE MONTH(date)=12 AND YEAR(date)=2013'; 
UPDATE temp_table SET ???;
INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM temp_table;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table;
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use temporary table at all:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (
  `date`, 
  `onefield`, 
  `twofield`
) 
SELECT 
  `date` + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, 
  `onefield`, 
  `twofield` 
FROM 
  mytable 
WHERE 
  MONTH(`date`)=12 
  AND 
  YEAR(`date`)=2013
```

Here `onefield` and `twofield` is some of your fields. I assume that `ID` is auto-increment field (so DBMS will substitute proper values). Note, that you'll have to recount your fields in query explicitly in this case.

Comment: That's a much better solution, thanks! But if there are already records on the next month before insertion, they should be replaced. I guess I need to send a delete command for the 'next month' before running this one?

Comment: That depends of what is 'replacing'. In the easiest situation - yes, just delete all records for next month.

Comment: I meant updating any existing records.

Comment: Updating - that's different case. You'll need to define what's updating (i.e. what's a matching condition for two rows and what should you update in the result)

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into your_table (c1, c2, ...)
select c1, c2, ...
from your_table
where date =2013-12-12;
```